# Excel VBA compile error: Expected Sub, Function or Property

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a compile error in Excel VBA which says Expected Sub, Function or Property. The function I am using is given below which is trying to copy the rate function in Excel.
Thanks for your help.

```
Function rate_m(nper As Double, pmt As Double, pv As Double, fv As Double, types As Double, guess As Double) As Variant
    Dim y, y0, y1, x0, x1, f, i As Double
    Dim FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS As Double
    Dim FINANCIAL_PRECISION As Double

    If IsNull(guess) Then guess = 0.01
    If IsNull(fv) Then fv = 0   
    If IsNull(types) Then types = 0

    FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS = 128 'Bet accuracy with 128
    FINANCIAL_PRECISION = 0.0000001 '1.0e-8

    y , y0, y1, x0, x1, f, i = 0
    rate_m = guess

    If Abs(rate_m) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION Then
        y = pv * (1 + nper * rate_m) + pmt * (1 + rate_m * types) * nper + fv
    Else
        f = Exp(nper * Log(1 + rate_m))
        y = pv * f + pmt * (1 / rate_m + types) * (f - 1) + fv

        y0 = pv + pmt * nper + fv
        y1 = pv * f + pmt * (1 / rate_m + types) * (f - 1) + fv
    End If

    'find root by Newton secant method
    i , x0 = 0
    x1 = rate_m

    While Abs(y0 - y1) > FINANCIAL_PRECISION & i < FINANCIAL_MAX_ITERATIONS
        rate_m = (y1 * x0 - y0 * x1) / (y1 - y0)
        x0 = x1
        x1 = rate_m

        If Abs(rate_m) < FINANCIAL_PRECISION Then
            y = pv * (1 + nper * rate_m) + pmt * (1 + rate_m * types) * nper + fv
        Else
            f = Exp(nper * Log(1 + rate_m))
            y = pv * f + pmt * (1 / rate_m + types) * (f - 1) + fv
        End If

        y0 = y1
        y1 = y
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **IF** ends with a **End If** (unless in a single line) and **While...loop**.  You might want to take a look at VBA's syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

EDIT: You have to declare variable individually, instead of:
    y , y0, y1, x0, x1, f, i = 0

you could do:
y = 0
y0 = 0
y1 = 0
x0 = 0
x1 = 0
f = 0
i = 0

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed to include End if and Loop ends with Wend. But still getting the same compile error.

Comment: @aphoria I've edited the answer.  I suppose they're all zero so didn't bother

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I tested it after I made the comment and your original code (`y = y0 = y1 = x0 = x1 = f = i = 0`) seemed to work. My mistake was testing with `0`...changing it to any other value does not work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @aphoria No worries I suppose both works but it's better to provide an answer that works in all senario (i.e. y0 = y1 = x0 = x1 = f = i = 1 won't works)

Answer (score 2):

A couple things...

First, you have to assign each variable individually...like this:

```
y = 0
y0 = 0
y1 = 0
x0 = 0
x1 = 0
f = 0
i = 0
```

Second, you probably want to `DIM` your variables all as `Double`. Unfortunately, this line:

```
Dim y, y0, y1, x0, x1, f, i As Double
```

Only declares `i` as a `Double`, all the others will be a `Variant`. You need to declare each one individually, like this:

```
Dim y As Double
Dim y0 As Double
Dim y1 As Double
Dim x0 As Double
Dim x1 As Double
Dim f As Double
Dim i As Double
```